# Solve equations stored as text in a dataframe column (using the other columns as inputs)

Tags: r, dataframe, equation

I have a data frame in R with a series of equations as a column and the variables to be used in the equation in additional columns:

```
df <- data.frame( equation = c('2+d','2+4+d*h','(5*d^h)/100'), 
                  d = c(1,2,3), 
                  h = c(1,3,4))
```

I want to use the values from d and h to solve the equation from their respective rows. Is that possible?

N.B. This is different to other SO questions that ask simply how to evaluate a formula stored as text:  This question asks how to use the other columns from within the same dataframe to populate variables in the equation column.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly the following (loop over each row) should work for the sample dataframe you provided:

```
df$equation <- as.character(df$equation)   # N.B. only needed if df$equation is a factor (as it is in your original sample data)

df$result <- as.numeric(NA)   # create an empty numeric column to store results

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$result[i] <- with(df[i,], eval(parse(text=equation))) 
}

df
     equation d h result
1         2+d 1 1   3.00
2     2+4+d*h 2 2  10.00
3 (5*d^h)/100 3 4   4.05
```

Above `parse()` is used to return the parsed but unevaluated expressions that are stored as text in df$equation.

`eval()` can evaluate an expression.

Using `with()` around everything (to make a local environment constructed from data) lets us refer to the column names without the df$ prefix.

In other words, the whole dataframe row `df[i,]` (all dataframe column names as variables in their own right) are available as variables to the `eval(parse())` call. So, for example for row 2, `d` and `h` can be evaluated within `eval(parse(text='2+4+d*h'))` as 2+4+2*2 = 2+4+4 = 10.

#### Edit

Just realized: In my version your sample data I created df using the option for **`stringsAsFactors = FALSE`** to ensure df$equation is character class in your df, rather than a factor.

If your actual data has df$equation as a factor then (unless you have a reason for wanting it to be a factor) for this exercise I suggest you either a) use the option for `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` or b) convert it to character at the very beginning of your code, for example using `df$equation <- as.character(df$equation)`

---

Sample data used:

```
df <- data.frame ( equation = c('2+d','2+4+d*h','(5*d^h)/100'), 
                   d = c(1,2,3), 
                   h = c(1,2,4), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```